# explain rsnapshot incremental rotation

Tags: backup, incremental-backup, rsnapshot

Need help on rsnapshot.
I am doing full backup every week with bash scripting which is costly for disk space. Now I am thinking to use rsnapshot and what I want to do with rsnapshot is do a weekly incremental backup and monthly full backup. So, this is how I configure the config file

**retain  gamma   4**
**retain delta   1**

and schedule cronjob

**00 00  * * *     root rsnapshot  gamma**
**00 00  1 * *     root rsnapshot  delta**

I have a root folder for rsnapshot /root/rsnapshots/.
Now with my understanding,
For every weekly incremental backup, it will create hard links in these folders and new incremental backup will be on gamma.0

- /root/rsnapshots/gamma.0
- /root/rsnapshots/gamma.1
- /root/rsnapshots/gamma.2
- /root/rsnapshots/gamma.3

and every month does it copy all gamma.3 content to /root/rsnapshots/delta.0 or does it copy all gamma.0 content to /root/rsnapshots/delta.0?

Could anyone please explain to me here, how this rotation works?
I am asking it because testing this kind of weekly and monthly rsnapshot is impossible for me with VM's.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

### Where does the data go to

First you have to understand that *only* the `gamma` (lowest level) backups actually copy any data, all the others just rotate (aka rename) and delete the already existing snapshots (the `gamma` does this aswell). (see below)

Second is that a hard linked file is just a single regular file appering in multiple locations in the file system. It will only be deleted once all appearances are deleted (it might still be present on disk after that, you just can't find it).

So no, your setup doesn't copy all data every month. The delta backups are just as incremental as the `gamma` ones. Just since you have only one `delta` backup it itself won't be incremental above anything else.

### What happens on every invocation

To understand what happens on each invocation of a backup-level, I highly recommend the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/rsnapshot.1.html), specifically the section about the `retain` parameter in the config. To give you a different explanation (I took me a while to grasp the manpage aswell):

#### Lowest level

Every time you (or cron) invoke `snapshot gamma`

- the `gamma.3` (the highest possible gamma backup) will be deleted if it exists. This causes any file revisions only present in that snapshot to be truly lost. All files that didn't change afterwards appear in `gamma.2` (as a hard link) and thus will persist. All files that didn't change since `delta.0` appear in `delta.0`.
- all `gamma.X` folders will be moved to `gamma.(X+1)`. This is a simple rename operation.
- a new snapshot `gamma.0` will be created incremental above `gamma.1`. Again all files that didn't change won't be copied but instead whatever is in `gamma.1` will just appear in the `gamma.0` folder aswell (as hard link).

#### Higher levels

Every time any higher level (in your case delta) is invoked the same happens for the respective level, except for the new snapshot part. Instead `gamma.3` (the last possible snapshot of the next lower level) is moved (aka renamed) to `delta.0` (the invoked level's `.0`). All the `gamma` backup still refer to the `delta` backup for old version.

#### Highest level

The only thing different here is that since there is no earlier snapshot, all file revisions that are outdated in `delta.0` (the highest level in your case) and would be present in `delta.1` will also be lost.

Another way to look at this would be: If you somehow could actually delete every file (not just it's apperance) inside `delta.0` (the last backup) *all* backups of files that didn't changed since then are gone.

PS: It is recommended to start the backup jobs from highest to lowest level, as otherwise the `gamma.2` folder will be rotated to `gamma.3` and then immediately to `delta.0` leaving you without a `gamma.3`. A small delay (10 mins) here is plenty, as only a few rename and delete operations are done by the higher levels. Also the `gamma` backups might take very long, as they copy data, causing the timing and order to get lost.